# QUERY a Data Extension in Parent BU from child BU

Tags: marketing-cloud

Is there any possible way to query (automation) a Data extension which is in Parent BU from Child BU (target being a DE in Child business unit)?

Answer (score 3):

To do this, you would have to make the share the data extension in the parent bu with the child.

As David pointed out, to access Data Extension outside the parent, you would need to prefix “ent.” to the DE name in the query

Comment: You will also need to prefix shared data extension with an "ent." in your query if the query resides in a child business unit.